# Retrieve a client's IP address with its MAC address via the DHCP server in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, ip-address, mac-address, dhcp

My question is this: I have, thanks to a PowerShell script retrieved the MAC address of my thin client. The script is executed on a client computer, and I want to contact, via my script, the DHCP server to recover the IP address assigned to my thin client. I am open to other solutions than contacting the DHCP server if you know others, but I need the current address and no possibility of failure and I would like to output the IP in a variable to display it.

I tried this but I think it only works from the DHCP server, but it's impossible in my case.
https://thewayeye.net/2016/10/8/find-a-mac-microsoft-dhcp/

I have this right now:

```
$mac
```

With this output:

```
847BEBEE****
```

I therefore need the IP address of the thin client from its MAC address from the DHCP server preferably to avoid errors due to the ARP table which does not always work due to the very large number of workstations in my network (large enterprise).

Comment: DHCP server cmdlets can be run remotely, but you need to install them on your client first (they're part of the RSAT). Alternatively run them on the DHCP server via `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: Yes I had thought about it but I don't know how to use this syntax, but above all, I don't know if this command will send me the answer from the DHCP server...

Comment: Only one way to find out ...

Comment: The DHCP server cmdlets are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dhcpserver/).

Comment: is the installation of RSAT administration tools mandatory on the client that runs the script?

Comment: if you want to use the DHCP cmdlets on the client: yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to simply retrieve the IP address via DHCP:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $dhcpserver | Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName $dhcpserver | where{$_.clientid -eq $macaddress}
```

The mac address format must be **xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx** (with dashes instead of colon)

However, you must install [the RSAT microsoft administration tools](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-FR/download/details.aspx?id=45520) and have the necessary rights on your account to query the DHCP server.

For information, to run powershell under another user pin it to the taskbar, "SHIFT+Right Clic" "Run with another user"